# changing delay in executorservice

Tags: java, executorservice

```
delay = 30;             

scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { .... }
            }, delay , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If the delay is changed to 60 at some later point, when is the job scheduled. At 30 seconds or 60 seconds?.

If we can't change the delay, what is the best way of doing it. I am planning on calling a shutdown(`scheduler.shutdown()`) and scheduling the job with new delay. Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `ScheduledFuture` from the `ScheduledExecutorService#schedule(..)` call.

When you need to reschedule, call `cancel()` on the `ScheduledFuture` and resubmit the task with a new `delay`.

Your tasks will probably need to be implemented in such a way that they can handle interrupts.